# ipywidgets interactive_ouput not interactive w/ jupyter-sphinx

Tags: python, jupyter, python-sphinx, ipywidgets

I am trying to embed an interactive widget in Sphinx built documentation. Specifically, I want a basic calculation based on two sliders to display. The sliders work fine when I build the HTML, but  the output is static (doesn't change based on the sliders). The following code works as expected when run in jupyter notebook, which makes me think it's something related to building the HTML.

I'm using `jupyter-sphinx` version 0.4.0.

Python code included below (simplified example):

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

a = widgets.IntSlider()
b = widgets.IntSlider()

def f(a, b):
    result = a*10 + b
    print(f'result: {result}')

out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'a': a, 'b': b})
w = widgets.HBox([widgets.VBox([a, b]), out])
display(w)
```

In the `.rst` file, I'm using the directive `.. jupyter-execute:: some_code.py`, where `some_code.py` contains the code shown above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!